# iOS build cannot resolve two Cocoapod dependencies with the same version

Tags: ios, cocoapods

In my iOS project I have a pod dependency which I am specifying like so:

```
pod 'PromisesSwift'
```

For some reason, the dependency `PromisesObjC` is appearing twice in the Podfile.lock, even when I delete this file and the `Pods` directory before running `pod install` and `pod update`.

```
  - PromisesObjC (2.2.0)
  - PromisesSwift (2.2.0):
    - PromisesObjC (= 2.2.0)
```

When I try and build this project on CI I get the following issue:

```
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "PromisesObjC":
  In snapshot (Podfile.lock):
    PromisesObjC (= 2.2.0)
  In Podfile:
    PromisesSwift was resolved to 2.2.0, which depends on
      PromisesObjC (= 2.2.0)
None of your spec sources contain a spec satisfying the dependencies: `PromisesObjC (= 2.2.0), PromisesObjC (= 2.2.0)`.
```

How does this make any sense? Both versions are identical and yet it cannot resolve them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was caused by the CI machine having old pod references.

The fix was to simply use the `--repo-update` option when running `pod install`.

```
npm ci --ignore-scripts
pod install --repo-update
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove Pods folder, xcworkspace and podfile .(Before remove podfile copy all pods).
After perform this steps.

```
$ sudo gem install cocoapods-deintegrate cocoapods-clean
$ pod deintegrate
$ pod cache clean --all
$ rm Podfile
```

After that add podfile and install pods.

Comment: Sadly this resulted in an identical podfile.lock and the same build error